# Is there any way to make tab bar stays anchored at the top, while the toolbar scrolls off?

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to do same scrolling technic as described in Material guidelines here: https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/scrolling-techniques.html#scrolling-techniques-behavior in "App bar with tabs" section.

Can't find any examples to do it. Is it possible in Flutter currently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the tab bar to stay anchored at the top, while the toolbar scrolls off. You can accomplish this using a `SliverAppBar` with                 [`pinned: true`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/SliverAppBar/pinned.html) and [`floating: true`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/SliverAppBar/floating.html). The full code for this sample is below.

[image: screenshot]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main() async {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new MyHomePage(),
  ));
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: new Scaffold(
        body: new NestedScrollView(
          headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
            return <Widget>[
              new SliverAppBar(
                title: const Text('Tabs and scrolling'),
                forceElevated: innerBoxIsScrolled,
                pinned: true,
                floating: true,
                bottom: new TabBar(
                  tabs: <Tab>[
                    new Tab(text: 'green'),
                    new Tab(text: 'purple'),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ];
          },
          body: new TabBarView(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Center(
                child: new Container(
                  height: 1000.0,
                  color: Colors.green.shade200,
                  child: new Center(
                    child: new FlutterLogo(colors: Colors.green),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              new Center(
                child: new Container(
                  height: 1000.0,
                  color: Colors.purple.shade200,
                  child: new Center(
                    child: new FlutterLogo(colors: Colors.purple),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: A problem with this arrises when I put lists on both pages. If I scroll one page down, the second page will also be scrolled down. Not as much but about the height of the TabBar I think, effectively obscuring the top of the list.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55260748/sticky-tabs-in-nestedscrollview-with-listviews